# UIView setAnimationTransition is not working?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewanimationtransition

i have added one view in UIwindow  as
         `[window addSubview:parVC.view];`

i toggle the `parVC.view` through the following , but it is not working

```
- (IBAction)flipToback:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                           forView:parVC.view 
                             cache:YES];
    [parVC.view addSubview:imgController.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I have set correctly `imgController.view` in IB in app delegate. I want to avoid window in forView. If i give window instead of forView:parVC.view , it works fine....

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the correct behavior to me.  `setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:` operates on the container view, not the one you're adding.

Comment: cant i use normal view instead of UIWindow?

Comment: Sure, you can add a view to the window and then add to rest of your views to that view